# Задать условие Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Вопрос , как задать условие | если cup.user = Иванов Иван тогда cup.Total (Относящийся к этому user ) + 10000 |

```html
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr class="info">
      <th class="text-center">Место</th>
      <th><i class="material-icons">
add_a_photo
    </i></th>
      <th>Менеджер</th>
      <th>Баллы</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | filter:comparator | orderBy: '-Total'">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{cup.Addon_1}}</td>
    <td>{{cup.user}}</td>
    <td>{{cup.Total}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Скрипт

```js
var CupApp = angular.module('CupApp', []);
CupApp.controller('CupCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  var number = $filter('number');

  function comparator(cup) {
    return number(cup.Addon_2, 0) != 2;
  }
  $scope.comparator = comparator;
    $http.get('.../total?' , { 
            params: { 
                 start : 20180402, 
                 finish : moment().endOf('year').format("YYYYMMDD") 
            } 
    }).success(function(data) {
      $scope.cups = data;
    });
  });
```

Массив вида

```
[
{
    "user": "Иванов Иван",
    "Department": "",
    "Total": 4599,
    "Addon_1": "-",
    "Addon_2": "-",
    "Addon_3": "-",
    "topuser": "-",
    "_4025": 2022,
    "_3039": 125,
    "B_3039": 1990,
    "_2022": 126,
    "B_2022": 1890,
    "_1015": 29,
    "B_1015": 290,
    "_2021": 7,
    "B_2021": 210,
    "_1011": 196,
    "B_1011": 196,
    "_1012": 23,
    "B_1012": 23
},
{
    "user": "Петров Петр",
    "Department": "",
    "Total": 3420,
    "Addon_1": "-",
    "Addon_2": "-",
    "Addon_3": "-",
    "topuser": "-",
    "_4025": 2022,
    "_3039": 48,
    "B_3039": 2139,
    "_2022": 61,
    "B_2022": 915,
    "_2021": 6,
    "B_2021": 180,
    "_1015": 11,
    "B_1015": 110,
    "_1011": 64,
    "B_1011": 64,
    "_1012": 7,
    "B_1012": 7,
    "_1014": 4,
    "B_1014": 4,
    "_1013": 1,
    "B_1013": 1
}
```

]

Comment: вот так и задать: `cup.user == Иванов Иван ? cup.Total+10000: cup.Total`

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | filter:comparator" ng-if=('cup.user == Иванов Иван ? cup.Total+10000: cup.Total ')> Так?

Comment: нет, нужно просто заменить содержимое в ячейке: <td>{{cup.Total}}</td>

Comment: Спасибо!Однако теперь | orderBy: '-Total' работает неправильно , как можно сделать сортировку по получившимся данным?

Comment: в таком случае лучше всего изменить значение при получении: `$scope.cups = data;` вместо простого присваивания что-то вроде `$scope.cups = data.map(cup=>cup.user == Иванов Иван ? (cup.Total+=10000, cup): cup;`

Comment: @Grundy $scope.cups = data.map(cup=>cup.user == 'Иванов Иван' ? (cup.Total+=10000, cup): cup; - при таком раскладе не выводится вообще никаких данных) , и как быть если мне надо задать нескольким юзерам разное кол-во. Например Иванову 10000 , петрову 20000

Comment: по аналогии с тем что есть

Comment: <td>{{cup.user == 'Иванов Иван' ? cup.Total+10000: cup.Total;cup.user == 'Петров Петр' ? cup.Total+20000: cup.Total}}</td> , я не понимаю как сделать перечисление условий =(

Comment: @Grundy <td>{{cup.user == 'Иванов Иван' ? cup.Total+10000,cup.user == 'Петров Петр' ? cup.Total+20000: cup.Total}}</td>

Comment: {{cup.user == 'Иванов Иван' ? cup.Total+15116 : cup.user == 'Петров Петр' ? cup.Total+15116: cup.Total}}

Comment: @Grundy Подскажи , что я делаю неверно? $scope.cups = data.map(cup=>cup.user == Иванов Иван ? (cup.Total+=10000, cup): cup; как ты и написал , после этого отваливается приложение.

Comment: Да вроде все ок. Хотя я не вижу закрывающей скобки после `cup);`

Comment: Да , верно) Спасибо $scope.cups = data.map(cup=>cup.user == 'Иванов Иван' ? (cup.Total+=10000, cup): cup);

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @Grundy
{{cup.user == 'Иванов Иван' ? cup.Total+15116 : cup.user == 'Петров Петр' ? cup.Total+15116: cup.Total}}